# Creating new feature for list each time when we create a list with same ListTemplate attribure

Tags: visual-studio-2012

We are facing following issues in SharePoint, when we create a custom list in visual studio a separate feature is created for each list automatically and type attribute in ListTemplate tag is set to 100, which should by default be auto generated unique id among that feature. This is causing issues when we deploy list.

This issue is arrising since we have created new development environment for SharePoint.

Old sharePoint environment was with visual studio Visual Studio Professional 2012 V 12.0.21005.1 REL

and new one is with SharePoint Server 2013 with latest cumulative update and Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 V 12.0.31101.00 Update 4

What can be the issue? How to proceed ahead ?

I will be pleased if you help me to solve the issue.

Thanks,
Prasad

Answer (score 0):

It is because features cannot contain [list templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms462947.aspx) that have identical values for Type.

> Type
>
> Optional Integer.
>
> Provides a unique identifier for the template. This identifier must be
>   unique within the feature, but need not be unique across all feature
>   definitions or site definitions. For a list of the default list
>   template types, see [SPListTemplateType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype.aspx).

You will probably find that your `Elements.xml` file for your list templates contains the same value for Type.

To fix this, you will need to edit the `Elements.xml` files of the `list template` and the `list instance`.

- Change the `Type` of the `ListTemplate xml` element to a unique integer.
- Change the `TemplateType` of the `ListInstance xml` element to the same integer
- You can set the numbers like 10001,10002,.etc.

Ref: [Visual Studio Unexpectedly Adding Feature on Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857722/visual-studio-unexpectedly-adding-feature-on-load)